# how to make field of type view in views align horizontal?

Tags: views, theming

There is no option for field type view in views to align horizontal like there is with the image field so does anyone know how to force it horizontal with css- what to call it before floating left? where in source it is:

```
 <span class="views-field views-field-view-1">  
    <span class="views-field views-field-view-2">
```

Comment: I think so you have enabled an option to show fields as inline ???
You can pick a class hierarchy to apply css properties.

Comment: don't know exact syntax for that to make work

Comment: can you share your site link? or screenshot if possible for better understanding

Comment: http://joanholt.tk/testimages

Comment: fields are align in this link. What do you want?

Comment: there is nothing in views for this field to render the class to align horizontal and i don't know how to write it in css.style sheet because syntax is wrong with whatever i try calling it.

Comment: in views you can create your custom css classes. For this edit views, click on filed in which you want to add class. Then under "Style Setting"  click first checkbox named "Customize field HTML" and then check "Create a Css class". Now in this field you can add your custom classes.

Comment: trouble is identifying the field in default classes

Comment: But according to my above comment you can just add class and apply your styles to that class.

Comment: i tried - it didn't work, how do you take this to chat if allowed?

Comment: anyway i am going to try again tomorrow- thx